# Multiple Joins using Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this query made in codeigniter using active record

```
$this->db->select('products_main.*, images_main.*, items_main.*, product_tags.*');
$this->db->from('products_main');
$this->db->join('images_main','products_main.product_tag = images_main.img_tag AND products_main.product_id = images_main.pro_img_id');
$this->db->join('items_main','products_main.product_id = items_main.pro_items_id');
$this->db->join('product_tags','products_main.product_id = product_tags.pro_tag_id');
$this->db->where('products_main.product_id',$p_id);
$this->db->where('products_main.status','active');
$this->db->group_by('products_main.product_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

My goal is to:

- Grab one product from products_main that matches the input from $p_id
- Grab all the photos for that one product from the images_main table
- Grab all the items that have the product_id of the product I have found
- Grab the row in the product_tags table that match the product_id of the product i have found.

I started a test fiddle here but have not filled out the query part yet as I do not know what to put.  [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a0b3)

Comment: I looked around and was unable to find enough data to figure out to how join three tables in codeignitor.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Variable is NULL, Which essentially means that I think there is no array from the sql i created.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using any variables in this query, so the "quick and dirty" solution is just to handwrite the query with `$this->db->query()`

Comment: i did that earlier in notepad and even tried to remove the joins then add them in one by one.  The images join seems to work well and bring up all the images for the product.  But when I add the other two, it goes haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any problem within your query, but as you group by `product id`, you may only get one result, but you can group by `image_id` instead, i've created the same in my localhost with the database you've created a fiddle and tried your solution, your only problem i see was as you don't join on left, the query can't find any exact matches, so try to join on left, also i've changed your query a little bit to prevent the database error with the given structure in your fiddle, so change it if you have them like that in your database ( commented them ) :

```
$this->db->select('p.*, im.*, i.*, pt.*');
$this->db->from('products_main as p');    
// img_tag -> image_tag
$this->db->join('images_main as im',
    'p.product_tag = im.image_tag
     AND p.product_id = im.product_id','left'); // pro_img_id -> product_id  
$this->db->join('items_main as i',
    'p.product_id = i.product_id','left'); // pro_items_id -> product_id
$this->db->join('product_tags as pt',
    'p.product_id = pt.product_id','left'); // pro_tag_id -> product_id
$this->db->where('p.product_id',"23"); // i have given example id as 23
$this->db->where('p.status','active');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I tried the example you posted and it almost worked.  For the images it works perfectly especially when i added the group_by(im_img_id).  However, for the items it only shows one item multiple times.  I tried to add another group_by(i.items_id) but that did not work.

Comment: yes it will do like that because of the structure of your query, because of that, you can extract `group_by` option from your query and loop all and extract duplicates, either you should write another query with splitting joins between two queries.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I think i will just split off the items table and complete that in a separate query as the other three seem to do well without it and there are no duplicates with the group_by added.  Thanks again for the awesome help.